# How can I create a function that returns a vector in R?

Tags: r

I want to create a function that returns its result as a vector. More specifically, a function that returns the divisors of an input value and places them inside a vector.

```
divisors<-function(n){
  i <- 2
  c<-1

  x<-c()

  while(i <= n) {
    if(n%%i==0) {
      x[c]<-i  
    }
    i <- i + 1
    c<-c+1
    x
  }        
}
```

Comment: You are trying to return `x` inside the `while` loop - return it outside that, just before the final `}`

Comment: Might be a better question for StackExchange. @Spacedman is correct -- move the x outside your while loop.

Comment: Are you just wanting a function that gives you the divisors of a number? If so, I'd suggest `numbers::divisors()`. If you're doing this as a learning exercise @Spacedman 's suggestion (and [paoloeusebi's related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53366504/8386140)) get you there, but looking at the code of `numbers::divisors()`, which uses `(1:n)[(n%%1:n) == 0]` could also be instructive.

Answer (score 0):

I edited a bit your code in order to return a vector and avoid  NA values.

```
  divisors <- function(n){
  i <- 2
  x<-vector("integer") 
  while(i <= n) {
    if(n%%i == 0) {
      x <- c(x, i) 
      }
    i  <- i + 1
    }        
    x
    }
```